# Dokku with SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, digital-ocean, dokku

I've read elsewhere that SQLite is not supported by Dokku. Why not? I'm using a Flask app with SQLAlchemy and it seems like that is where all the abstraction is taking place. Couldn't I just place the sqlite database file somewhere on disk (/home/dokku/database/my_db, perhaps?) and give that to SQLAlchemy?

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite://///home/dokku/database/my_db')
```

More specifically, I would use Dokku to store that string as an environmental variable, rather than pass it in directly.

Why wouldn't this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why wouldn't this work?

Dokku creates containers via Docker, and your application runs inside this container and its file system. Besides, your flask apps doesn't have access to `/home/dokku` [by design](http://12factor.net/backing-services).

Depending on your specific needs and as long as you have a single docker container:

- use a path inside the container (e.g. /app/db.sqlite). This works as long as the app's container exists. Note however, that for all purpose you should consider the file system of a Dokku app as temporary.
- map a host file that is resident on the dokku host, e.g. using the [dokku-persistent-storage](https://github.com/dyson/dokku-persistent-storage) plugin.
- use [docker data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container). At time of writing this, there doesn't seem to be a dokku plugin, but it is relatively simple to make (needs a `create` command to create a data container, a `link` command to link it to the app, finally a `dokku-args` hook to generate the arguments to `docker run`)

Comment: Nowadays (dokku > 0.5) you would use the built-in dokku storage plugin http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/dokku-storage/ to map and mount folders as persistent storage location.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm a bit late, however, this is largely because Dokku uses docker images, which do not have access to the host OS (meaning `/home/dokku/database/my_db.db` doesn't exist, as far as the application is concerned).

Another factor is that Dokku is designed to be an open-source "clone" of Heroku, which also doesn't support persistent file storage in this fashion (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3)